# Doubt about definition of infinite limit and limit as x tends to infinity

Tags: definition, epsilon-delta, constraints

In the limits and continuity chapter in my textbook, the following definitions are given:

(1)  For limit of f(x) as x tends to infinity:

We say that $ƒ(x)$ has the limit $L$ as $x$ approaches infinity and write $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L$ if, for every number $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a corresponding number $M>0$ such that for all $x>M,   |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

(2)  For infinite limits:

We  say that $ƒ(x)$ approaches infinity as $x$ approaches $x_0$, and write $\lim_{x\to x_0 } ƒ(x) = \infty$, if for every number $B>0$ there exists a corresponding $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, 
$$0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies f(x) > B$$

What I don't understand is why the numbers M and B have to be greater than zero in the first and second definitions respectively. I think the definition would work without this added constraint, i.e. if M (and, similarly,  B) is *any real number*. 
So, I don't understand why this condition is present in the definitions.

Since I couldn't find any discussion on this topic anywhere on the net or in my book, I have asked this question.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're right. The demands of  $M$ and $B$ are positive are superfluous.

Comment: @MathOverview, but then why are they included in the definitions?

Comment: I think it's just to stay consistent with the other limite definitions.

Comment: @MathOverview You should write that as an answer.